# send parameter to Javascript from c#

Tags: javascript, .net, vb.net, postback

I have some problems on javascript. I am sending parameter to js sending data is:

[image]

coming javascript is:

[image]

c# code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ' JSonID.Value = "{""id"":""1"",""name"":""1"",""data"":""0,3048"",""children"":[{""id"":""11"",""name"":""11"",""data"":""0,3048"",""children"":[{""id"":""111"",""name"":""111"",""data"":""0,3048"",""children"":[]},{""id"":""112"",""name"":""112"",""data"":""0,3048"",""children"":[{""id"":""1121"",""name"":""1121"",""data"":""0,3048"",""children"":[]},{""id"":""1122"",""name"":""1122"",""data"":""0,3048"",""children"":[]}]}]},{""id"":""12"",""name"":""12"",""data"":""0,3048"",""children"":[]},{""id"":""13"",""name"":""13"",""data"":""0,3048"",""children"":[{""id"":""131"",""name"":""131"",""data"":""0,3048"",""children"":[{""id"":""1311"",""name"":""1311"",""data"":""0,3048"",""children"":[]}]},{""id"":""132"",""name"":""132"",""data"":""0,3048"",""children"":[]}]},{""id"":""14"",""name"":""14"",""data"":""0,3048"",""children"":[]}]}"
    'ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel1, Me.GetType(), "GraphFunction", "drawChart()", True)

    If Page.IsPostBack AndAlso GraphNames.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then
        SetGraph(GraphNames.SelectedIndex)
    End If

    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        OnOffCheck.Items.Add("On")
        OnOffCheck.Items.Add("Off")
        Menu1.Items(0).Selected = True

        StaticService.CreateErrorDictionary()
        RunDBInfo()

        Label4.Text = ""
        If Page.IsPostBack AndAlso GraphNames.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then
            SetGraph(GraphNames.SelectedIndex)
        End If
    End If

    Dim graphString = jSerializer.Serialize(ObjList)
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel1, Me.GetType(), "GraphFunction", "drawChart('" & graphString & "')", True)

End Sub
```

Javascript code:

```
 function drawChart(graphInput) {
        //                                        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        //                      ['X', 'Points', 'Line'],
        //                      [3, 3.5, 1],
        //                      [4, 5.5, 2],
        //                      [4, 5, null],
        //                      [6.5, 7, 3],
        //                      [8, 12, 4],
        //                      [11, 14, 5]
        //                    ]);
        //  alert(1);
        // var data = JSON.parse('<%=jSerializer.Serialize(ObjList)%>');
        alert(graphInput);
        var data = JSON.parse(graphInput);
        alert(data);
        dLen = data.length;

        var tabledata = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  ...
```

What is the problem ? how can i recieve data properly in javascript ?

Comment: That's not `C#`. That appears to be `Visual Basic .NET`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`graphString` is not being initialized as a string. You didn't specify a type so therefore `Object` is assumed. Does `jSerializer.Serialize(ObjList)` actually return a string? If so, try initializing `graphString` as a proper string:

`Dim graphString As String = jSerializer.Serialize(ObjList)`.

Comment: you are perfecto !! . i could not understand how i did not see object problem :( By the way, i could not understand why visual basic does not give any error :s

Comment: There was no error because what you had before was syntactically correct (at least without having Option strict turned on). It was just that you wanted to send a string variable to javascript but you were sending an object variable instead. In fact I'm thinking that you would have been able to get it to work the original way as well by converting the object to string in javascript, but I think passing the string from the beginning is a better solution.